# Python declaring multiple variables as lists

Tags: python

Is the below declaration wrong? It doesnt give any syntax error though but some times i see that `b` and `a` value append operations do not work in case of a list.

```
a=b=c=[]
 or 
a=b=c={}

a=b=c=1 //works
```

Comment: you are binding `a`,`b`, and `c` to the same list/dict.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried it?

It depends what you mean by "wrong". It's not a syntax error, but it does mean that `a`, `b` and `c` refer to the *same* list. So if you subsequently append something to `a`, you'll see it in `b` and `c` as well.

Comment: what i wanted to say is that if the language supports something like a=b=c=1 ;b=2;a=1,b=2,c=1 that should hold good for the arrays too

Comment: Rajeev, it does! If you followed the statement with `a=[2,3]; b=[4,5]`, that would work. The difference is that `a.append(3)` changes the object to which `a` points, whereas `a=[2,3]` makes `a` point to something new.

Answer (score 4):

```
a=b=c=[]
```

works, but doesn't do what you want. It creates *one* list object and associates three different names with it:

```
a.append(1)
print b # [1]
```

What you want is probably:

```
a, b, c = [], [], []
```

Now a, b and c are three independent lists.

Answer (score 0):

Python lists and dictionaries are mutable. Read discussions in the link below.It gives you a very good idea of what you want to experiment with

http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/lib/typesseq-mutable.html

Answer (score 0):

Several other answers correctly say that `a=b=c=[]` make all three names refer to the same list object. There is another point, however: in Python, you don't *declare* anything. You need to make the names `a`, `b` and `c` into empty lists only if you want to append to them. Otherwise you can just set them to whatever you want.